# microsoft.mashup.container.loader.exe blocks deleting file

Tags: excel, vba, windows, process, system

I've faced the problem with deleting file by VBA
My code imports a text file, then close the import table and deletes this text file to pick another. This code was working for about a year ok, but last 2 weeks appeared an error while deleting file
[image]

Kill patchn & j & ".txt"' where `patchn` is a path

I've [surfed the web](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoftmashupcontainerloader/20a6e619-8685-486c-8cb0-f11fa1c1fc8a) what's the error and how to fix and found a code to close and unload the process via PowerShell

```
Private Sub KillMashupContainer()

    ' Macro to kill power query background process that stops queried files from being deleted

    Shell "taskkill.exe /f /t /im Microsoft.Mashup.Container.Loader.exe"

End Sub
```

But the problem is that sometimes it's working and sometimes not. I've put the pause between KillMashupContainer and deleting file and it started to go OK

```
Call KillMashupContainer
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Kill patchn & j & ".txt"
```

But for some users this pause works on no less then 5 sec for others immediately. Maybe it's just coincidence.
Questions:

1. What does this error depend on? It appeared only for some users under the same corporative license and the same system and office configuration.
2. Does the closing of the process really need time?
3. How to 100% fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error with my scripts accessing files on the network from multiple machines. One that collects timestamps and writes them to a file and one that opens the files to get the timestamps into a table via query.

It seems this is a function of how the query imports the data and whether it's done immediately and doesn't continue with any other function until the query is complete vs. having the query run in the background.  I believe the "running in the background" is supposed to relieve stress on the processor if there is a lot of data to process.

There is a setting within Excel that is supposed to alleviate this but I find it a bit finicky.  I've unchecked "Allow data previews to download in the background" under Data>Get Data>Query Options and select Data Load under Current Workbook.  This didn't seem to work at first so I saved the workbook then reopened it and it still didn't seem to work but after a short while it did and any subsequent reopening of the workbook seems to have continued to work.  Monitor with task manager until you have enough confidence that it will continue to work.

Here's a snapshot of that area.
[Excel Workbook Query Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPvnc.png)

I don't know if you'll be able to view the pic yet as I'm a newb to the site.

I have not been able to determine what the timeframe is for this "process" to run.  For me It can run indefinitely unless I manually stop it or close the workbook.
The above solution may work for you.

Additionally,  I don't know if unchecking this box will work if you share or distribute your workbook.  You'll have to test that as well.